# How to create global content for a GRAV CMS

Tags: twig, yaml, grav

How can I localize content though out my Grav CMS? For example I have some footer content in both english and french. So rather than hardcoding the content for my footer, I need it to be dynamic so that if the user goes to the french route of the site, the content inside the footer while change to french. It would be ideal if I could just keep those localized content inside a YAML file and then pull it out something like {{footer.title}}.

If you have any ideas that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are various options in the [Multi-Language](https://learn.getgrav.org/content/multi-language) section of the docs but it looks like you're looking for translation via Twig

```
<h1 id="site-name">{{ "SITE_NAME"|t }}</h1>
<section id="header">
    <h2>{{ "HEADER.MAIN_TEXT"|t }}</h2>
    <h3>{{ "HEADER.SUB_TEXT"|t }}</h3>
</section>
```

Then in `\system\languages` create an `en.yaml` with something like this

```
SITE_NAME: My Blog Site
HEADER:
    MAIN_TEXT: Welcome to my new blog site
    SUB_TEXT: Check back daily for the latest news
```

Comment: That is awesome! thank you so much. Quick question, we a re using jsonToYaml in our gulp file to convert the data over for us. Is there a way to just include a file with the convert jsonToYaml into the en.yaml file? Because the only concern is that we would be deleting all the pre added cntent inside the en.yaml file whenever we run our gulp. Or is the content that was already included in the en.yaml file basically irrelenvet for the most part?

Comment: Also do you know how I would loop through an array in this file. I cant seem to get her to work.

Comment: Sorry not sure, might be better as a separate question, you could maybe have a step combine the concatenate en.yaml (you could rename it to en-old.yaml so the new file is en.yawml) but I think you'd probably just replace this with your content.